# Consume web service secured with a username and passwords is using WS-Security in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

how to consume a service secured with username and password in .NET? , I am able to consume it in SOAP UI as attached.when I pass username and password in soap UI, it works, the question is how to do that in .NET

I tried using below code in .net app

```
var client = new EpmAPI.STC_ERP_EPM_API_PortTypeClient(); 
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "XXX";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "XXX";
var basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential); basicHttpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;
var headers = new EpmAPI.SOAHeader();
var param = new EpmAPI.InputParameters3(); param.P_PO_NUMBER = "";
var output = client.SEARCH_PO(headers, param);
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
</startup>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="XXSTC_ERP_INTEG_EPM_API_Binding">
                <security mode="None">
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="STC_ERP_EPM_API_Binding" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address=".../webservices/SOAProvider/plsql/xxstc_erp_integ_epm_api/" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="XXSTC_ERP_INTEG_EPM_API_Binding" contract="WO_Service.XXSTC_ERP_INTEG_EPM_API_PortType" name="XXSTC_ERP_INTEG_EPM_API_Port" />
        <endpoint address="...../webservices/SOAProvider/plsql/stc_erp_epm_api/" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="STC_ERP_EPM_API_Binding" contract="EpmAPI.STC_ERP_EPM_API_PortType" name="STC_ERP_EPM_A
```

I am getting error Missing wsse:Security in SOAP Header

Comment: Don't post your code in comments, post it in your question.

Comment: `BasicHttpMessageCredentialType` is for HTTP `Basic` authentication, it is not for authentication using WS-Security. You'll need the details for how to configure WS-Security from the SOAP service's operator.

Comment: [Again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63722305/consume-http-soap-web-service-wsdl-using-username-and-password-in-net) If people tell you to fix a question, fix the question. Don't post a duplicate question without explanations. This should be closed as a duplicate of the other question

Comment: In any case the generated WCF client wouldn't miss headers. Nor would it need manually adding any headers. How did you generate this client? Why are you generating the bindings manually instead of just using the client??

Comment: Did you try to use the client, got an error and assumed it needed some kind of fixing? Did you manually add the `Basic` bindings even though `Add Service Reference` used `WS-Security` bindings? Try creating a *new empty project*, eg a Console application, and just add a Service Reference to that service *without any modifications*. Call it *without trying to hard-code the binding*, just set the credentials. If you get an exception *post the full exception text* in the question, not just parts of the message. The full text contains any inner exceptions and the full stack trace that led to it

Comment: You can easily get the exception text with `Exception.ToString()` or clicking on the `Copy Details` link in the exception popup. Post the `system.ServiceModel` section of the unmodified app.config to the question as well. It should use `wsHttpBinding`, not `basicHttpBinding`

Comment: If it doesn't, it may be a problem with the *service*. SOAP and WS-* are very strict but some vendors take liberties with the standards. The SOAP standard was first created by Microsoft while other vendors (eg Oracle) tried to push other protocols. Even after SOAP won out, other vendors tried to use their protocols through non-standard extensions. The WS-* interoperability standards were created to over come this, with Microsoft a driving force. As a consequence, WCF conforms to these (strict) standards. It's possible that some other vendor's stack partially violates the standard

Comment: I tried to consume the service and calling the client with auto-generated binding but got the same error Missing wsse:Security in SOAP Header

Comment: it is working in SoapUI bceause i am passing username and password in request properties